How to read a file in hex in node.js?
I have this function to read the first bytes of a file and return the result, but it never work with asar files:
function readAsarHeader(filePath) {
  try {
    // Asegurarse de que la ruta del archivo sea válida
    filePath = path.resolve(filePath.replace(/\\/g, '/'))

    // Verificar si el archivo existe
    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
      throw new Error(`El archivo no existe: ${filePath}`)
    }

    // Leer los primeros 16 bytes del archivo
    const headerData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, { start: 0, end: 15 })

    // Los primeros 4 bytes son una firma, los siguientes 4 bytes son el tamaño del encabezado JSON
    const headerSize = headerData.readUInt32LE(4)
    
    // Leer el encabezado JSON
    const jsonHeader = fs.readFileSync(filePath, { start: 8, end: 8 + headerSize - 1 })
    
    // Parsear el encabezado JSON
    const header = JSON.parse(jsonHeader.toString())

    return header
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al leer el encabezado ASAR:', error)
    throw error
  }
}

This is the error I get:
renderer.js:63 Error al abrir o procesar el archivo ASAR: Error: ENOENT,  not found in
D:\\mods\\app.asar
at createError (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:2002)
at t.readFileSync (node:electron/js2c/node_init:2:10345)
at readAsarHeader (renderer.js:17:27)
at HTMLButtonElement.\<anonymous\> (renderer.js:41:22)


You are reading the first four bytes of the file as the header size.  That's incorrect.  The 4-byte header size is wrapped in a "pickle" object, which occupies 8 bytes.  The first bytes have the size of the field (which should be 4).  There is a Javascript package to read asar files: https://github.com/electron/asar .
